# Braintree payment gateway: Dealing with "payment_method_token"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I'm new to brain tree payment gateway. I can't understand that what is `payment_method_nonce` (token provided by end user) or how this token is generated ?

Also I dont know how to get the customer card details, how to store it, and how to do transactions with the "payment_method_token"

```
result = Braintree::PaymentMethodNonce.create("A_PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN")
nonce = result.payment_method_nonce.nonce
```

Can any body explain how to create or get `A_PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN`?

Comment: Please clarify how to create CreditCard for the customer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **paymentmethodtoken** is a unique identifier for the customer's credit card that we use to make purchases.

If you check the result object you can extract the payment method token from it and can be stored in your side for future transaction for the same user without entering the card details.

[image: Sample Braintree Result Object]

This is required to save the payment method nonce as a payment method token. The payment method nonce can only be used once, where the token is a reusable value that will not expire.

You’ll need to first [create the customer and](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/customers/ruby#create-with-payment-method) payment method in one call, and then use the payment method token [from the result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/ruby#token) to [create the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/ruby). Keep in mind that you will need to first [create a plan in the Control Panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans), but you can [override most of the plan details](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/ruby#overriding-plan-details) when you create the subscription.

After you create a Customer with a stored payment method you can use the returned token to subscribe a user to a plan. This article explains it well:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview

**A Real Time Example by Site point Team on How to Integrate Braintree Can be found in the bellow link:**

[Integrate Braintree Payments into Rails](http://www.sitepoint.com/integrate-braintree-payments-rails/)

Answer (score 2):

`payment_method_nonce` is the params that your braintree form submit to your controller.

You can use `nonce_from_the_client = params['payment_method_nonce']` to create braintree `Transaction`

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :amount => "100.00",
  :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client
)
```